# How to find when specific line was introduced?

Tags: perforce

In my codebase; I see line <123> is in a specific file; and i'd like to see when it was introduced.  I can do 'p4 annotate' to find when it was last  modified; but i'm sure there is a way to step back to introduction..   I'm using 2009.2; not the latest if that matters...

-Chris

*edit*

This was probably a bad question; I solved my problem by walking back the tree until finding where it was added, basically..

p4 annotage  | grep

p4 annotage myFile#rev-1 | grep

p4 annotage myFile#rev-1 | grep

Comment: Um, the change that modified a line is the change that introduced it. You would have to use heuristics to determine that "Well, this line was an edit of that other line, so now I will look for the change that modified that other line." Or are you asking for help developing that heuristic?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have p4v installed, you should use the time-lapse view.  That will give you an accounting of all lines in the file, who introduced or changed those change, what changelist, etc.  Timelaspse is an awesome tool and will give you what you need without needing to resort to grepping through old versions.

Answer (score 1):

Solution in ruby

```
file = "/path/to/your/file"
period = "#8,10" # could be @2012/10/01,@now
$all_authors = []

def find_changed_lines file, period
    puts "File: #{file}#{period}"
    ls = `p4 annotate -a #{file}#{period}`.split"\n"

    a = []; b = []; prevrev = ""; linen = 0; authors = []

    # find [first, last] aka [min, max] file revisions for given period
    ls.each{ |l| l[ /^([0-9]+)-([ 0-9]+):/ ]; a<<$1.to_i if $1; b<<$2.to_i if $2; }
    first = a.min.to_s; last = b.max.to_s

    # find changed lines
    ls.each{ |l|
        l[ /^([0-9]+)-([ 0-9]+):/ ]
        # find line number
        linen +=1 if $2==last
        # reject lines if #not changed line or #itermediate change
        unless ($1==first and $2==last) or ($1!=first and $2!=last)
            # find rev#
            rev = $2==last ? $1 : ($2.to_i+1).to_s
            # print cl desc info based on rev# unless printed for prev line
            if prevrev != rev
                cldesc =  `p4 filelog -m 1 #{file}##{rev} | head -2 | tail -1`
                puts cldesc
                # collect change author
                authors << cldesc[/by (.*)@/, 1]
                prevrev = rev
            end
            # print changed line with line number
            puts l.sub(/^.*:/, "#{linen}:" )
        end
    }
    puts "Change authors: #{authors.uniq!.join(', ')}"
    $all_authors += authors
end

find_changed_lines file, period
```